# Pycharm Django CSS not updating after adding git repo

Tags: python, django, git, pycharm

I am creating a website and I was designing it without a repository set up originally. Now, I have it in a git repo and suddenly, when I try to refresh the page (with dev tools open and cache disabled) my CSS and HTML changes have no affect. I have to stop the server, close the webpage, then re-run the server and open it again to see changes. Anyone experienced this? Not sure what gives.

Comment: This almost certainly has nothing to do with the presence of a Git repository.

Comment: Yes I see that, I answered my own question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this myself. Classic correlation does not equal causation. The reason that this was not working was because I had set my debug to False in settings.py when I added it to git repo (because I was deploying it). Once I set it to true it updates every time now.